# What to do with $(undefined)?

Tags: jquery, undefined, undefined-behavior

I accidentally came across `$(undefined)` in a statement below, where `params` is an object:

```
var $this = $(params._this) || $(this);
```

This did not work, as `$(params._this)` is a jQuery object and is always evaluated to `true`.

Funny enough, I was not sure how to check for it. It is not an empty object (i.e. `$.isEmptyObject($(undefined)) == false`), nor is it a function or a "plain object" (i.e. `$.isPlainObject()`).

I ended up modifying the statement to the following:

```
var $this = (params._this == undefined) ? $(params._this) : $(this);
```

My question is, is there any way to "evaluate" (not sure what word to use) `$(undefined)`? Is there any use for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var $this = $(params._this || this);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$(undefined)` is just an empty jQuery object; it's equivalent to `$()`. Sometimes it's used instead of `$(document)` in the common idiom `$(document).ready(...)`.

Comment: This is useful to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The most suitable way in your case seems to be what DanC said, but you can check for an undefined jquery object by checking it's selector :

```
$(undefined).selector == ''
```

In your case :

```
var $this = $(params._this).selector != '' ? $(params._this) : $(this);
```